# Como cambiar valores en arrays dentro de arrays

Tags: php, array

En el siguiente código llamo a la base de datos pidiéndole todos los trabajadores y intento desencriptar un campo, por algún motivo no funciona la parte en la que manejo los valores de estos. aquí el código:

```php
$sql="CONSULTA";
if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $trabajador[] = $row;
    }//hasta aqui todo funciona
    for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($trabajador) ; $i++) { 
        $untrabajador[]=$trabajador[$i]; //aquí entiendo que paso un trabajador "entero" al array $untrabajador
        $campo=$untrabajador['campo']; //aquí me quedo solo con el iban y trabajo sobre el
        $ciphering = "$$$$$$$$";
        $iv_length = openssl_cipher_iv_length($ciphering); 
        $options = $$$$$$$$$;
        $decryption_iv = '$$$$$$$$$$$$$$';
        $decryption_key = "$$$$$$$$$$";
        $campo=openssl_decrypt ($campo, $ciphering,  
        $decryption_key, $options, $decryption_iv); 
        $untrabajador['campo']=$campo; //el iban desencriptado lo devuelvo a su lugar
        $trabajador[$i]= $untrabajador; //devuelvo el trabajador de vuelta a su sitio
    }
    echo json_encode($trabajador);
}
```

Se que el error tiene que estar en como manejo los arrays pero he agotado mis ideas.

entiendo que si en *$row* (linea 4) puedo hacer *$row['campo']* en ***$untrabajador*** (linea 8) también debería poder hacerlo

Answer (score 0):

es una solución que me permite realizar una consulta y añadir mas datos a la base de datos de la consulta el código es un poco diferente pero permite dar una solución

```
<?php
class dbConnect
{
    private $host = "localhost";
    private $user = "root";
    private $pass = "";
    private $db = "appexpres40";
    private $conn;


    public function Connect()
    {
        $this->conn = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->db);

        if ($this->conn->connect_errno) {
          printf("Falló la conexión: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
          exit();
        }  
    }

    public function consultaDB($tabla)
    {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM {$tabla}";
        //echo "query -> " . $query;
        $result = mysqli_query($this->conn, $query);
        return $result;
    }
    
}

$tb = new dbConnect();
$tb->connect();
$resultado = $tb->consultaDB("roles");
//$da = $resultado->toarray();
//var_dump($resultado);//;exit();
    $data=[];
    while ($row = $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        array_push($data,$row);
    }
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        echo $value['id'].'<br>';
        echo $data[$key]['control']='ssss';//.'<br>';
    }
    var_dump($data)
```